# 2d Arraydeque insertion

Tags: java, arraydeque

I am using arraydeque to store another arraydeque of type Integer.
My code looks like this:

```
    private ArrayDeque<ArrayDeque<Integer> > grid;
    public void initiateGrid(){     
    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        ArrayDeque<Integer> columns = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
        for (int j = 0; j < Width; j++)
            columns.add((int)(Math.random() * 100));
        grid.add(columns);          
    }
}
```

When I try to run this it gives me a NullPointerException on grid.add(columns).
does anyone know what am I doing wrong?
Also if there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialize `grid`, because you cannot use a null object, otherwise you get `NullPointerException`

```
 public void initiateGrid(){ 
    grid = new ArrayDeque<ArrayDeque<Integer>>();
    //...
 }
```